# spaces not needed in case labels?

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

May be this is a silly question, but did anyone already know whether or not there would be a mandatory space between the `case` keyword and its constant expression in the `switch` statement?

The standard seems not say anything about...

Consider the following code:

```
switch(int_expression)
{
    case1:     /*anything*/  // no space before 1
    caseZERO:  /*anything*/  // no space before ZERO
                             // ZERO being defined as 0
                             // by the pre-processor
}
```

Both my reference compilers accept this code and once run it works nicely.
How does the preprocessor recognize that ZERO must be substituted?

Note also that if the control expression was a `char` type instead of a `int` type the following is also compiled but this time it no longer works

```
switch(char_expression)
{
    case'a':   /* anything */  // NO SPACES embedded
    caseZERO:  /* anything */  // NO SPACES again
                               // ZERO being defined as '0'
                               // by the pre-processor
}
```

THIS COMPILES but even if the value of the `char_expression` was '0'
no statement in `caseZERO` is executed.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: An identifier followed by a colon is also a label (for use with goto). I'll bet that is what `caseZERO` is in this context. I would also expect the rules which control this are in the section which defines what a token is, and the grammar expects a token `case` but gets a token `caseZERO`. `ZERO` is also not expanded for the same reason. But I'm no expert in the standard, so I'll let someone else answer.

Comment: interesting. i wonder what the standard says about a switch with no case labels

Comment: @sp2danny: It probably allows them, but will skip over the switch statement/block -- similar to an if (0)

Comment: There needs to be whitespace separating the `case` word from it's value *in order for the compiler to recognize the `case`*.  As others have stated, without the whitespace, the identifier is treated as a label (e.g. for a `goto` statement).

Comment: @sp2danny: That's perfectly valid, the syntax is `switch ( expression ) statement`, even `switch(0);` is a valid no-op.

Answer (score 8):

These are general labels for use with [`goto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto) and won't actually match the expression as you intend. The syntax is valid, but the semantics are different.

You don't specify whether this is a C compiler or a C++ compiler, so here's the documentation for [`goto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/goto) in C as well.

Also, if you look in the actual grammar provided by the ISO C standard in Appendix A.2.3 (6.8.1) defines a *labeled-statement* as follows:

> (6.8.1) *labeled-statement:*
>
> *identifier* **:** *statement*
>
> **case** *constant-expression* **:** *statement*
>
> **default** **:** *statement*

Note specifically that the `case` is a single token which must be followed by at least one token separating character in the context of the grammar. A numeral as in your example of `case1` does not count as a token separating character, so your example falls into the first branch of the grammar which is an *identifier* **not** a `case` statement, and thus can't be used as the target of a `switch` statement.

To answer your other question regarding `ZERO` being defined in a preprocessor macro, the substitution **is not happening** as you believe. Again, the preprocessor operates on tokens, and thus `caseZERO` is a single token which does not match the `ZERO` macro and so will not be substituted at all. Again, this is just defining a *labeled-statement* using the *identifier* branch where the identifier is the entire token `caseZERO` and not `case0` or `case'0'` as you believe. The preprocessor does have means of doing "token pasting" using the `##` operator, but that would require you to use `case ## ZERO`. However, this still would not have the behavior that you probably intend.

Answer (score 3):

The type of the case expression is not relevant. It's the syntactic form that matters.

```
switch (expr) {
    caseZERO: /*...*/;
    case0:    /*...*/;
    case'a':  /*...*/;
}
```

`caseZERO` and `case0` are both valid identifiers. In this context, they are *labels*, but not *`case` labels*. If you had a statement

```
 goto caseZERO;
```

or

```
 goto case0;
```

in the same function, it would branch to the corresponding labeled statement.

(This is one of the many cases in C where a typo results in code that's still syntactically valid, but with a substantially different meaning.)

`case'a'`, on the other hand, is *two* tokens, because the `'a'` is a *character constant*. (But it should still be written as `case 'a':` for the benefit of the human reader.)

The rules for splitting source code into tokens require white space between an identifier, keyword, or numeric literal and another identifier, keyword, or numeric literal, because otherwise it would be ambiguous. They do *not* require white space in other contexts. That's why, for example, you can write:

```
 x=y+func(42);
```

rather than

```
 x = y + func ( 42 ) ;
```

Adding *some* white space will make the code more legible to human readers:

```
x = y + func(42);
```

but the compiler doesn't care.

(Another case where whitespace is important is in the definition of a function-like macro. The `(` must immediately follow the macro name; otherwise it's treated as the first token of the expansion rather than introducing the parameter list.)

Comment: Thanks to all for your valuable answers: now all is clear to me...the question was truly silly.